# Meaning of verb form 'es algo que *inhiere* en ellas'

Tags: definiciones, verbos

In the following sentence:

> advertimos que la forma accidental que configura al bronce como estatua o a la madera como silla es algo que **inhiere** en ellas, que se encuentra en esa materia como en su sujecto.

What is the verb corresponding to `inhiere` and its meaning in this sentence?

Comment: Probably derived from *in-* + *herir*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb would be [`Inherir`](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/inherir) meaning

> Ser [inherente](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=inherente) a algo (Constituye una característica imprescindible e inevitable de algo; Que por su naturaleza está de tal manera unido a algo, que no se puede separar de ello)

That sentence means that the *accidental form* that turns bronze into a statue or wood into a chair is inherent in them. It is found both in that matter as in its subject.

Comment: +1 Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is a very little detail Diego, one I would sent you by private message if there was something of that kind here. 

the way you translated the last part of the citation, I would have translated differently. I would say «it is found in that matter as in its subject /as if it were its subject» or something similar. Do you think this could be one possible translation?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea., probably better not to have private messages, so other can share their opinions too. Yes, you are right, the proper translation should be something like "the accidental form that turns bronze into a statue or wood into a chair is inherent in them. It is found both in that matter as in its subject", but I don't thin that "as if it were its subject" applies that well. Do you think that this translation conveys better the message in the context of the book you are reading? If so I'll update my answer with the newer translation.

Comment: Yes, I think so. The first form of translation, from the ones I gave, allows for the second form of translation, which is the message of the book in that section. Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Intrínseco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M03Jhd5) o que es íntimamente asociado a [algo]

Comment: +1 for your answer also. Thanks

Comment: "Está" would work better than "es" in this context.

Comment: Actually, Diego, I think *es* would be better here. And it should be *o* rather than *ho*.

Comment: @NicholasJ., interesting. I would say that "A **está** íntimamente asociado a B" not that "A **es** íntimamente asociado a B", since there doesn't seem to be a third party to do the association (but is just for this context).

Comment: @Diego I agree with you, 'está asociado' makes more sense, at least in everyday/day-to-day language.

Comment: @Diego, my bad, I had read "[...] que es inherentemente asociado a [...]"